# How do I access a website hosted on a Virtualbox guest OS from host OS

Tags: virtualbox, website, host, guest

I have Windows XP, in which I have installed a Windows Server 2003 VM on Virtualbox.

I have hosted my website in the guest server with IIS.

I am able to access that site by using following link in the guest OS

```
http://localhost/Test/index.aspx
```

The IP address of the guest is 172.16.1.10

I want to access the web site from the host OS. I am trying the following URL in Internet Explorer

```
http://172.16.1.10/Test/index.aspx
```

but I am not able to access the site. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the virtualbox network configuration to bridged, This way it will put itself inside of the same network as the host and I think you might have more luck connecting to it.

Comment: +1 Given all the problems created by the NAT mode I really wonder why the default isn't bridged mode, which in most cases is the only mode that makes any kind of sense.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Because of only one reason, Security :D